# I have pandas dataframe with 3 columns and want output like this

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

DataFrame of 3 Column

```
a   b   c               
1   2   4               
1   2   4               
1   2   4
```

Want Output like this

```
a   b   c   a+b a+c b+c a+b+c
1   2   4   3   5   6   7
1   2   4   3   5   6   7
1   2   4   3   5   6   7
```

Comment: • Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide more information on what you have tried, and why it didn't work. Demonstration of the effort and a [minimal code and data to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required for the question to be accepted. Take a minute to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([pd.np.array(j).sum(0) for i in range(2,4) for j in combn(df.T.values.tolist(),i)]).T],1)`

Comment: NameError: name 'combn' is not defined Showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create all combinations with length 2 or more by columns and then assign `sum`:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031
comb = chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(df.columns, x), range(2, len(df.columns)+1)))

for c in comb:
    df[f'{"+".join(c)}'] = df.loc[:, c].sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   a  b  c  a+b  a+c  b+c  a+b+c
0  1  2  4    3    5    6      7
1  1  2  4    3    5    6      7
2  1  2  4    3    5    6      7
```

Comment: Why cant `combinations` take a function as an argument?. They should update it, the same way `R's` combination takes in a function as an argument. in eg we should be able to do`combinations([1,2,3,4], 2, sum)==> [3,4,5,5,6,7]`

Comment: @Onyambu - I think because there are only 2 input parameters, check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: yeah was checking that and wondering why they cannot update it to take in another argument

Comment: Can we count frequency of 1 in column 1, frequency of 2 in column 2 and frequency of 4 in column 3 and on.....

Comment: @jezrael- Thanks, i was not aware about "accept". Ok, i am creating new question please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You should always post your approach while asking a question. However, here it goes. This the easiest but probably not the most elegant way to solve it. For a more elegant approach, you should follow [jezrael's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) answer.

Make your pandas dataframe here:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 1], "b": [2, 2, 2], "c": [4, 4, 4]})
```

Now make your desired dataframe like this:

```py
df["a+b"] = df["a"] + df["b"]
df["a+c"] = df["a"] + df["c"]
df["b+c"] = df["b"] + df["c"]
df["a" + "b" + "c"] = df["a"] + df["b"] + df["c"]
```

This gives you:

```py
|    |   a |   b |   c |   a+b |   a+c |   b+c |   abc |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|------:|------:|------:|------:|
|  0 |   1 |   2 |   4 |     3 |     5 |     6 |     7 |
|  1 |   1 |   2 |   4 |     3 |     5 |     6 |     7 |
|  2 |   1 |   2 |   4 |     3 |     5 |     6 |     7 |
```